# Login not working with Devise, suspect encrypted_password issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using Devise - can log in via omniauth-twitter and via my admin user, but regular users get a 401, even after password reset link. On password reset, Devise logs in user, but if you logout and try to log in, get a 401. If I create a new user, it won't let me log in.

In checking user records, it doesn't seem to be generating the hash for encrypted_password on save. If I check using .valid_password? "password", I get false, even after resetting password.

I am running Ruby 2.3.1 + Rails 4.2.7.1 + Devise 4.4.1

Nothing in the sessions_controller.rb

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: [:username, :customer_id, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, address_attributes: [:name, :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip]]
end


def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if admin_user_signed_in?
    admin_root_path
  else
    if request.env['omniauth.auth']
      provider = request.env['omniauth.auth'].provider
      session["login.#{provider}"] = provider
    end
    edit_user_registration_path
  end
end

end
```

sessions/new.html.haml

```
     = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
        = devise_error_messages!
        .field
          = f.label :email
          %br/
          = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true
        .field
          = f.label :password
          %br/
          = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off"
          - if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations'
            = link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name), class: "right small"
        %br/
        - if devise_mapping.rememberable?
          .field.small
            = f.check_box :remember_me
            = f.label :remember_me
        .actions.center
          = f.submit "Log in", class: "waves-effect waves-light btn"
      = render "devise/shared/links"
```

routes.rb

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions", passwords: "users/passwords", omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'}, skip: [:sessions, :registrations]

  devise_scope :user do
    get    "login"   => "users/sessions#new",         as: :new_user_session
    post   "login"   => "users/sessions#create",      as: :user_session
    delete "signout" => "users/sessions#destroy",     as: :destroy_user_session

    get    "signup"  => "users/registrations#new",    as: :new_user_registration
    post   "signup"  => "users/registrations#create", as: :user_registration
    put    "signup"  => "users/registrations#update", as: :update_user_registration
    get    "account" => "users/registrations#edit",   as: :edit_user_registration

    put 'update_plan', :to => 'users/registrations#update_plan'
    put 'update_card', :to => 'users/registrations#update_card'

  end
```

Console output:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x0ACUBAv4MPdK2DmFvIC0c/PqiWgD+AK/+Z2VxMmtWrGvFrKcgs+gLdbJcxUo1W8QWTP2ccbDdX6WOLu0ATovQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"joshdfadafakl@gotostepone.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]","remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to include your code and the actual output of testing you've done.

Comment: Done. Not sure if anything else would be relevant, as it is mostly stock Devise